# Do cathode rays produce radiation?

Tags: electrons, atomic-physics

When electrons accelerate, they produce radiation. So do cathode rays also produce radiation. In books and google, it is mentioned that electrons in cathode rays sometimes strikes the glass causing fluorescence. Shouldn't cathode rays be visible by itself since are accelerating electrons? Or is it that the radiation they emit is outside of visible light?

Comment: maybe this https://www.instructables.com/DIY-Cathode-Ray-Tube-Interacting-With-Electrons/

Answer (score 0):

It was known for years that television CRT's did indeed emit small amounts of X-rays when the electron beam struck the front face of the tube and interacted with any metal atoms in the glass or the screen structure that delineated the phosphor array on its surface. As TV tubes grew in size so did their acceleration voltages and by the end of the 1960's, when color TV tubes were 23" in diameter and contained three separate electron guns, people were warned not to let their children sit too close in front of the TV for long periods of time because of those X-rays. I do not know exactly what the resulting dosage levels were, however.